# this.function is not a function error, but function exists

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have some code to get calendar events and display them. The display is only updated if the events have changed, since the last call.

```
var calendar = {

    events = null,

    display_calendar_events : function (data) {
        // Some display stuff...
    },

    get_events: function() {

        // Get messages for calendar
        $.getJSON("/ajax/get-events/", function(json){

            var new_events = json.data;
            // If events haven't changed, do nothing
            if (this.events === new_events) {
                return true;
            }

            // Events have changed. 
            // Save new events
            this.events = new_events;

            // Display new events
            this.display_calendar_events(json);
        });
   },
}
```

I call this with:

```
calendar.get_queued_events();
```

The problem is, I'm getting the error **"this.display_calendar_events is not a function"** (last line of code).
But if I change this line to:

```
calendar.display_canendar_events(josn)
```

it works. The storing of the old events with "this.events" works fine in both cases.

Can someone explain this to me? How can "this" work for some stuff and not others? Thanks.

Comment: Inside the callback, `this` refers to something else (the `jqXHR` object afaik).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What context is the jQuery.post callback function invoked in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064392/what-context-is-the-jquery-post-callback-function-invoked-in)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a jQuery AJAX callback, `this` references the ajax request object. Try using `var self = this;` before your AJAX call, and in the callback use `self.display_calendar_events()`.

Alternatively, you could just reference `calendar.display_calendar_events()` directly. But that's not easily refactored like the `self` method is.

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with jQuery or AJAX, this is simply the way closures work in JavaScript.

Comment: This explains why it's failing. Thanks. But why does this.events still work? Shouldn't this fail for the same reason?

Comment: @Aine `this.events` is a property, not a method. Javascript objects are dynamic, so when you check `this.events` you just get `undefined`, and setting `this.events` creates a new property on `this`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call this.display_calendar_events() inside the ajax request you area ctually in a different context than your object. You have to do:

```
var calendar = {

events = null,

display_calendar_events : function (data) {
    // Some display stuff...
},

get_events: function() {
    var $this = this; 
    // Get messages for calendar
    $.getJSON("/ajax/get-events/", function(json){

        var new_events = json.data;
        // If events haven't changed, do nothing
        if ($this.events === new_events) {
            return true;
        }

        // Events have changed. 
        // Save new events
        $this.events = new_events;

        // Display new events
        $this.display_calendar_events(json);
    });

   },

}
```

Comment: I suggest to add comments instead of using `**`.

Comment: You are right, that's why I never downvote for such little things, but leave a comment instead. Anyways, to avoid such situations, test your code before you post it.