# jQuery and replacing hyperlink with HTML code loaded from the server

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML code has about 100 divs and hyperlinks which are almost identical:

```
<div><a href="#" onclick="load_edit(1, 1);" class="painike">Edit 1</a></div>
<div><a href="#" onclick="load_edit(1, 2);" class="painike">Edit 2</a></div>
```

My jQuery code should load load_edit.php from the server and replace the hyperlink which called the function. Anyway, my code does not replace a hyperlink with HTML code, and I do not know the reason. What is wrong?

```
function load_edit(kaavio, ottelu) {
  $.post( "load_edit.php", { kaavio: kaavio, ottelu: ottelu } )
    .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );

      $(this).replaceWith(data); // this does not work
  });
}
```

On the other hand, because I have about 100 hyperlinks which are calling the same function, it would be nice to hear, how this could be done better. I would like to get rid of my inline JavaScript code and improve the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `$(this)` doesn't refer to the DOM element that was clicked.
For more information, see [What context is the jQuery.post callback function invoked in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064392/what-context-is-the-jquery-post-callback-function-invoked-in)

> When you create an anonymous function, it will hold onto all local variables in the same scope, but not `this`, which is set by JavaScript itself (to the global object) or overridden when called.
>   — [Yehuda Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122162/yehuda-katz)

I suggest binding a click handler to all links with the appropriate class. Then, define a reference to the clicked element before making your AJAX call. This local variable will then be available in the anonymous "done" function.

I also suggest using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to define variables per link. This data can be retrieved from the DOM by using jQuery's [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method.

```js
jQuery('.painike').on('click', function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      kaavio = $this.data('kaavio'),
      ottelu = $this.data('ottelu');

  jQuery.post("//posttestserver.com/post.php", {
      kaavio: kaavio,
      ottelu: ottelu
    }).done(function(data) {
      $this.replaceWith(data);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a href="#" class="painike" data-kaavio="1" data-ottelu="1">Edit 1</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="painike" data-kaavio="1" data-ottelu="2">Edit 2</a></div>
```

Here's another seemingly relevant post, though it's not exactly a duplicate:
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177917/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createdocumentfragment-of-undefined)

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about using href="#" on my hyperlink. Better ways?

Comment: I think the `#` is fine, but there are [varying opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-to-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0). You might want to cancel the default action of the links by using [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return false;`. If you really want to be accommodating, you could link to a page that explains that JavaScript is required.

Comment: I had to add $(document).ready(function(){ (do not know the reason) and after that your code works perfectly! Thank a lot.

Comment: Sounds good. If your JavaScript loads before the DOM, you may need to use [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to wait for the DOM to load before binding your click handler. See [Why document.ready is used in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753333/why-document-ready-is-used-in-jquery).

Comment: If I want to use style <a href="#" class="painike muokattavaksi"..., how should I modify the jQuery code? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't appear that adding another class will affect your JavaScript. That is, unless there is some other conflicting JavaScript bound to the "muokattavaksi" class.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `.done()` callback, `this` does not refer to the clicked element.  Instead, you can pass the element reference into `load_edit()`.

```
<div><a href="#" onclick="load_edit(1, 1, this);" class="painike">Edit 1</a></div>
<div><a href="#" onclick="load_edit(1, 2, this);" class="painike">Edit 2</a></div>

function load_edit(kaavio, ottelu, element) {
    $.post("load_edit.php", { kaavio: kaavio, ottelu: ottelu })
        .done(function (data) {
            $(element).replaceWith(data);
        });
}
```